# Raspberry Pi 3 returns input/output error and crashes system when trying to update on 64GB card

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm trying to set up my Raspberry Pi with a 64GB micro-SD card using the image file `2018-04-18-raspbian-stretch-lite`.

Every time I try to update or install software on the card, the system gives me the following error message:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
unable to sync directory '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - pkgDPkgPM::Go (30: Read-only file system)
```

The system then refuses to run any more programs and I cannot access the system again after I log out. (I normally access my Raspberry Pi via SSH.) I've checked the filesystem on the card, as per [this article](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/sdxc_formatting.md), and Disk Utility is telling me the card is FAT32, so that doesn't seem to be the issue; and besides the article says the card shouldn't even boot up the first time if I was using the wrong filesystem.

I have tried installing Raspbian on two different 64GB cards now and have got the same result on both. Additionally, I tried doing the same thing on a 16GB card and it worked normally.

Comment: I do not think it is to do with memory size of the card , but the way it is formatted, try visiting the raspberry forum , https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=66

Comment: Try to ask at a dedicated SE site for Raspberry Pi as well - https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you, I have created a question on [Raspberry Pi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88476/raspberry-pi-3-returns-input-output-error-and-crashes-system-when-trying-to-upda).